# Tensor product symbol and convolution

Tags: notation

The convolution of $f$ and $g$ is sometimes written as $f\ast g$ and sometimes as $f \otimes g$.

Is convolution denoted by both of these symbols because the operations are related, or is it just historically determined? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) and Google dont know.

Comment: In the differential equations texts which I own, the notation $f*g$ is used for convolution. I have not seen $\otimes$ used for convolution... however, notation varies.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Professor Cook, the convolution isn't a example of Tensor? Because exist a isomorphism between the tensor product $V \otimes V$ and the space of all bilinear functions $L(V^{*} \times V^{*} ; \mathbb{R})$ . Maybe the notation is due to the operation tensor product $f \otimes g$.

Comment: @M.N.Raia perhaps, I'm not well-versed in enough of the abstract analysis needed to sort through the terminology. My previous comment was given from my admittedly limited knowledge about convolution. More recently, I taught a course which touched on abstract Fourier analysis etc. and I see that convolution has a much broader meaning than I realized when I last commented. Is the convolution a tensor product ? Well, it is bilinear in each entry so.. what else do we need ? Tensor product of what exactly ? Functions, I suppose, it is a function-valued tensor then.

Answer (score 1):

In the neural networks (e.g. in Tensorflow) there are convolutional layers which use a tensor product. The latter symbol stands for tensor product. It is not applicable in all convolution-scenarios.